# Vide.js looping through multiple videos

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using vide to play a video background on my website. I want to play one video then a second video before looping back to the first video again. Can / has this be done using vide. If so has anyone got any code

Kind regards
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

run the second video when first one is ended

```
video.onended = function(e) {
//run the second vidio
}
```